# Handbook of advanced data structures

Tags: soft-question, ds.data-structures, survey, books

I am looking for a book on advanced data structures that goes beyond what is covered in standard textbooks like Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein's "Introduction to Algorithms".
A book that can be used for teaching a graduate level course on advanced data structures like Erik Demaine and André Schulz's [Advanced Data Structures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-851-advanced-data-structures-spring-2010/lecture-notes/) course at MIT. 
An encyclopedic handbook of data structures would be even nicer.

Comment: there are advanced structures in significantly different fields as the class lists eg graphs, computational geometry, info retrieval, strings etc, and each field is likely to cover each separately, they do seem very different... maybe better combined in a class than a book...

Comment: @vzn: You're right — different subfields use different structures — but the tools overlap more than you might expect.  Graph data structures, string data structures, and info retrieval data structures are all used in computational geometry, for example.  Kaveh is posing a well-known open problem among data structure researchers.

Comment: agreed however it would seem roughly the more advanced the datastructure in a field, the less likely the overlap. there is of course strong overlap between basic structures (eg graphs, strings, info retrieval etc)....

Comment: If many data structures researchers want such a handbook (and from the answers below I'm getting the sense that we do) then why isn't there one?

Comment: @Joe: Everyone is waiting for someone else to take the plunge.

Answer (score 14):

I wish I had a good answer for you. I use [Book:Fundamental Data Structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book%3aFundamental_Data_Structures) (a collection of relevant Wikipedia articles) for [my course on this subject](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/261/) but it's not really a complete textbook (for one thing, it has no exercises). CLRS is, I think, at a good level of detail for this sort of class but is missing too many of the important structures.

Answer (score 10):

The only advanced data structures book that I'm aware of is the one by Peter Braß ([Advanced Data Structures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521880378)). It's not a bad book, but I'm not convinced that it's truly advanced at the graduate level.

Answer (score 9):

The [Handbook of Data Structures and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584884355) (Chapman & Hall/CRC Computer & Information Science Series) is mostly devoted to elementary data structures, but it also contains a few advanced materials that you may find useful for teaching a graduate level course. Given the huge size (1392 pages), this book may be classified as an encyclopedic handbook of data structures, even though certainly it is not an handbook focusing primarily on advanced data structures.

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure no such book exists.

I drew up an [annotated bibliography](http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/datastructures/schedule.html) for [my recent course](http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/datastructures/), which was loosely based on Erik's course at MIT.  It's definitely [incomplete](http://compgeom.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/datastructures/schedule.html#nope)—I covered very few geometric data structures and *no* text data structures, for example—but you might still find it useful.